# Angular and moment.js : should I convert fields taken from json string to Date or moment.Moment?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I have following data structure returned from api call (when editing user profile):

```
 export class User {
     username: string;
     email: string;
     creationTime: Date;
     birthDate: Date;
 }
```

I also use Angular Material DatePicker for editing this value (**birthDate**). I need to validate date after user enters it (in frontend) and also parse it from string to Date/moment.Moment and back to string when sending value to backend. What is more preferable way to declare it as model class field? Should I use native Date type and use moment.js just for manipulation of dates or is it more convenient to just use moment.Moment as type without using Date type at all?

What with **creationTime** if I want just to display it for user, should I just declare it as string type in frontend?

And last question - should the conversion take place in service call to backend api (while parsing output, e.g. with reviver function) or is it somewhat better to convert strings in model constructor call?

Comment: If I were to do it, I think I would stick with Moment if that is the only way that you will be interacting with the date field. That way you don't have to do conversion every time you go to use the date fields and it would help with keeping consistency.

Comment: @dmoore1181 and where would you apply conversion? In service method calling api parsing observable result (e.g. with reviver), in constructor of User model, or in component?

Comment: I removed moment.js from all of my projects due to bundle size and especially due to mutations. I'd recommend date-fns instead. It works with native js dates. Adapter might look like this: https://gist.github.com/JoniJnm/412325c073805437c68430b11407e11b

Comment: Thank you, Can K., for posting your adapter, I think I will consider changing to date-fns. 

I chose moment.js , because I read it's most popular and it seems to have good docs and also I didn't consider bundle size as critical factor for my app. I see also that for moment.js I can just import adapter without declaring it (it would be good for date-fns to also have this possiblity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the documentation says:

> **Setting the selected date**
> The type of values that the datepicker expects depends on the type of DateAdapter provided in your application. The NativeDateAdapter, for example, works directly with plain JavaScript Date objects. When using the MomentDateAdapter, however, the values will all be Moment.js instances. This use of the adapter pattern allows the datepicker component to work with any arbitrary date representation with a custom DateAdapter. See Choosing a date implementation for more information.
>
> Depending on the DateAdapter being used, the datepicker may automatically deserialize certain date formats for you as well. For example, both the NativeDateAdapter and MomentDateAdapter allow ISO 8601 strings to be passed to the datepicker and automatically converted to the proper object type. This can be convenient when binding data directly from your backend to the datepicker. However, the datepicker will not accept date strings formatted in user format such as "1/2/2017" as this is ambiguous and will mean different things depending on the locale of the browser running the code.

https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

So if your dates are ISO 8601 strings then you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It gives me new look for the issue, and kind of simple solution.